# How can I terminate a process by it's location? C#

Tags: c#

I'm sure this is really easy but I have googled frantically for a while now and cannot fathom this out.

I've listed all the processes I want to delete in a listbox, *showing the location as you can have many instances of this running from different locations,* I then want the user to be able to select any process in that list box and kill it.

Because the process name is the same but I want it to kill it based on location.

My code for getting it populated in the list box is as such:

```
public void getProcess()
        {
            Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd");
            foreach (Process proc in localByName)
            {
                lb_instances.Items.Add(proc.MainModule.FileName);
            }
        }
```

the output looks like this:

> C:\folder1\lmgrd.exe
>
> C:\folder2\lmgrd.exe
>
> C:\folder3\lmgrd.exe

I want something along the lines of

```
Process.Kill(lb_list.SelectedItem.TosString())
```

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every process is uniquely identified by a number, you should store that against it. Been a while since I did Windows dev, but you could do something like this. Let's create a class to store our data:

```
public class ProcessInfo
{
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when we get our list of process in the new format:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("lmgrd")
    .Select(p => new ProcessInfo
    {
        ProcessId = p.Id,
        Name = p.MainModule.FileName
    });
```

We need to set up the `ListBox` to use the correct properties of our new class:

```
lb_instances.ValueMember = "ProcessId";
lb_instances.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Add our processes to the `ListBox` in one go (no need to loop here):

```
lb_instances.Items.AddRange(processes );
```

Now when you want to choose a process, do this:

```
var processId = (int)lb_instances.SelectedValue;
Process.GetProcessById(processId).Kill();
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the route I was literally about to go down so that's reassured me.